# How to extract data from a HTML Input field in django. Data needs to be extracted from a form which exists in the html file

Tags: python, html, forms, django-2.0

A frontend developer has given me a front-end layout which consists of html forms. I being a backend developer need to fetch the data from the form and store it in the database. I am using django version 2.0 for the website development. I donot want to use django forms as then I will be forced to make a lot of changes in the html code. How can I extract data from input fields in the HTML forms?

---

Let us say the we have a simple HTML form in a file index.html
myapp/templates/index.html
In the form, the data must be sent using post method only.

```
<form action="{% url 'myapp:update' %}" method="post">
<input type="text" name="first_field"/><br>
<input type="text" name="second_field"/><br><br>
<button type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

The purpose of the form is to update the database.
myapp/models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

myapp/urls.py

```
 from django.urls import path,include
 from . import views
 app_name='myapp'
 urlpatterns = [
 path('index/', views.index, name='index'),
 path('update/', views.update, name='update'),
 ]
```

myapp/views.py
In views.py file,   any element in the form can be fetched using

```
 request.POST['nameOfTheFieldInTheForm']
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {})

def update(request):
    # print('Inside update function')
    if request.method=='POST':
        # print("Inside post block")
        first_field_data=request.POST['first_field']
        second_field_data=request.POST['second_field']
        x=Person(first_field=first_field_data,
        second_field=second_field_data)
        x.save()
    return index(request)
```